# \ref shows names of referenced objects

Tags: cross-referencing, chemstyle

For some reason when I reference something in my text, it also gives the type of object referenced (like Tabel 1, instead of just 1). I understand, that this is not standard latex behavior, but I do not explicitly load packages, that should alter this. I guess, one of the packages I use silently does this.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, english, parskip, a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[journal=angew]{chemstyle}   % loads chemscheme, graphicx

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
        \caption{Test}
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            Test \\ 
        \end{tabular}
        \label{tab:test}
    \end{table}

    Look at Table~\ref{tab:test}.
\end{document}
```

This will print

> Look at Table Table 1.

How can I get rid of this? Thanks!

Comment: Try unloading `chemstyle` ...

Comment: `chemstyle`loads `varioref`. You can turn it off by adding the option `varioref=false`: `\usepackage[journal=angew,varioref=false]{chemstyle}`

Comment: `chemstyle` also centers the content of the environment.

Comment: @DG' This was actually the solution. If you turn this into an answer, I will select it.

One question still arises. The documentation of chemstyle only states, that it is loaded, but not what it is used for. Any ideas?

Comment: In text I prefer  " ... Table 1 ..." with an uppercase 'T', since that Table is a proper noun.

Comment: @EthanBolker You are absolutely right. I should remove the reason for why I was asking from my question. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The package `chemstyle` loads `varioref` by default. This can be turned off with the option  `varioref=false`. The relevant line in your example would therefore read:

```
\usepackage[journal=angew,varioref=false]{chemstyle}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your support.